# comparative construction used with pronouns, especially 'her'

Tags: personal-pronouns, comparatives

I was recently pulled up by a colleague when I made a statement along the lines of *I am a better player than her*. My colleague suggested the correct statement should be *better player than **she is*** because *her* is a possessive pronoun, and my colleague was waiting to hear what noun *her* referred to.

I was unconvinced. I am able to say:
*I am taller than Jim*, which can become *I am taller than him*. 
So, just because *her* is both the feminine possessive and personal pronoun why does that exclude me from saying *I am taller than her*?

Or, have I made a false assumption, and should never have a noun/pronoun without a verb at the end of a comparative structure? Should I always have been saying *I am taller than Jim **is***, and *Rabbits are faster than turtles **are***?  This seems awfully cumbersome

Comment: 'her' is also an accusative pronoun, which is how i functions in your first example sentence.

Comment: "Taller" is an adjective while "better player" is a noun phrase.  I think that's probably a factor in the explanation but I don't have a formal rule for you.

Comment: @Monica: I don't think that makes any difference. Both *taller than* and *a better player than* are adjectival phrases. When we're talking about idiomatic usages like this, deconstructing to any lower level probably doesn't get us anywhere. Even at the next level up, where we follow on with *she, she is,* or *her*, we're still looking at adjectival phrases, and the actual preferred usage is primarily dictated by idiomatic convention rather than logic or "old-school" grammar.

Comment: @Jim: Apart from it being more cumbersome, I think you personally should avoid saying *"I am taller than Jim is"* on the grounds that it may be logically confusing for the rest of us! :)

Answer (score 8):

I think your colleague may be getting at the idea that *than* is a conjunction, not a preposition. This is a long-running dispute. Those who argue that *than* is a conjunction, claim that it is followed by a clause in which the verb phrase can be elided. When that happens, the only word left must be the subject of the clause. Since *her* cannot be a subject, it would be considered wrong. Other people consider *than* to be a preposition. If that's the case, then they reason, a pronoun following it would be an object, so *her* would be correct. Both forms are used, but the *than she* form is formal in register while the *than her* is neutral.

Comment: I had also played around with _better than she_ but it seemed a different kind of wrong:  by using the subject pronoun (she) without a verb where I'd expect an object one. And yes I agree, it also seems overly formal

Comment: which is to say that '... better than she.' is ...I was about to say 'wrong' but it should not be considered grammatical, except that it is becoming more and more common.

Comment: +1 really good answer. Explains different ways people are being prescriptive, in a descriptive way.

Comment: @Mitch: If you're suggesting *"I'm better than she"* is ungrammatical then I have to disagree. Over the last 2-3 centuries it's becoming more common to either append *"is"*, or switch to *"her"*, but none of them are ungrammatical or "wrong".

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the possesive pronoun has the same form as the accusative of the personal pronoun is what seems to be at the origin of this confusion. You also can say: *Look at **her**!* or *I asked **him**.* These are examples that clearly imply the use of accusative and they're perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a matter of logic or grammatical correctness - it's about idiomatic usage.

Grammatically, it's fine to say *"I am taller than he"*, and I suspect this form may even have been *more* common than either *"he is"* or *"him"* a century or two ago. It just sounds a bit dated/stilted/formal today.